# dealing with success: and error: in an MVC3 client to server validation routine using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side, server-side

I am working on a validation routine that needs to go back to the server, perform a bit of database checking and then return to the client to display messages depending on the outcome.. I am using MVC3, Javascript, Ajax.

This is my clientside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#usrid').change(function (e) {

    var formData = $("form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ValidateOfficers",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.reponseText);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.reponseText);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller action:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("ValidateOfficers")]
    public ActionResult ValidateOfficers(userRole role)
    {
        int holderid = role.holderid;
        int roleSelected = role.roleid;
        int chosenUser = role.usrid;
        int countRoles = db.userRoles.Where(i => i.roleid == roleSelected && i.holderid == holderid).Count();

        if (countRoles == 0) //success:
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.Write("ok");
            return View("Create", role);
        }
        if (countRoles > 0) //error:
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Response.Write("error");
            return View("Create", role);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

What I want to do perform the count and then send back a status based on the count result.. So if countRoles = 1 then return text "officer exists" if countRoles > 1 then "duplicate records exist". if countRoles is zero then I can assume success and offer no message.

Ok, I am stuck on how to built this custom message on the server side and how to post it back to the client. I was thinking of adding a couple of labels to the razor and show/hiding depending on the count result.. As you can see I have had a very basic go, but to no avail. I get "undefined" in the alert messages currently.

If I can get some tips on this I would be most grateful!!

Comment: "I get "undefined" in the alert messages currently." That's because `data` **is** your response text.

Comment: ah ok - how do I hydrate data with a text from the server in that case?

Comment: What does `alert(data)` display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Action**

```
public ActionResult ValidateOfficers(userRole role)
{
  string myMessage;
  \\ here goes all of your other code
  \\ set value into myMessage depending on your conditions.

  return Json(new {foo=myMessage});
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#usrid').change(function (e) {

    var formData = $("form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ValidateOfficers",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.foo);

            if(data.foo == "exists")
            { // do something (show/hide msgs)
            }
            else if(data.foo == "duplicate")
            { // do something else (show/hide msgs)
            }
            else
            { // do something else (show/hide msgs)
            }

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.reponseText);
        }
    });
});
```

and you also would want to read [this article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-an-action-from-javascript-or-jquery-in-mvc-3-razor/), for knowing how to return json data.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thank you - that is a really helpful post & article. I have it working a treat now :-)